# Is it possible to use an Apple gift card toward repairs?

Tags: repair, apple-store

I have a gift card whose balance should just about exactly cover the cost of some repairs Apple is doing on my computer. Is it possible to spend a gift card on repairs? I assume so, but I cannot find any confirmation on Apple's website. Just wondered if anyone on here had any experience to confirm or disconfirm.

Comment: You can even pay part with the gift card, the rest with cash or other payment. Just be sure it's not an iTunes store gift card - those are not valid on the web store and retail stores.

Comment: @bmike yup, that's exactly what I did, with great success.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the card can be used in an Apple retail store (i.e. not an iTunes gift card), then yes. Repairs are treated as an in-line item in their POS system. Any valid form of payment that could be used to pay for anything else in the store can be used to pay for repairs.

I called an Apple retail store to confirm this.

Comment: Thanks for making the call for me! Sometimes I forget that the "phone" can be a valid source of info...

Comment: @michael +1 for thinking to call the store.

Answer (score -4):

From the [Apple Gift Card Page](http://store.apple.com/us/personalize/apple?product=MA210LL/C):

> The pressure's off. Now your friends and family can **choose almost
>   anything that Apple offers in its huge collection of Mac and iPod
>   products at any Apple Store** in the United States - online, by phone,
>   and at an Apple Store near you. Just give an Apple Gift Card and the
>   recipient can choose from qualifying products.

Clearly just for buying a subset of products, not for repairs.

Comment: This is incorrect - Apple Gift Cards (which are different than iTunes gift cards) are acceptable forms of payment for anything that is sold in the Apple Retail Stores - repair services are processed through the same iPod touches as the rest of the things you buy there. Your repair paperwork gets scanned with a barcode scanner, your gift card gets swiped as a credit card would, you leave with your mac as long as enough funds are there to cover the repair.

Comment: Adding a data point here - was told by Apple Chat that Apple ID balance (which is redeemed by Apple Gift Card) cannot be used for AirPods Pro case replacement cost. Very frustrating.